# Linux on Hard Drive Partition, Bootloader on USB Flash Drive

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, usb-drive, boot-loader

How can I use a USB flash drive to boot Linux from a partition on (another) hard drive?

I'm trying to install Linux on an encrypted partition on the hard drive (using LVM on LUKS).

Since `/boot` must be on a separate, unencrypted partition, I would like to store it on a USB flash drive.

My plan was to install GRUB (2) to the flash drive (`/dev/sdb`) and boot Linux from it's MBR, or if the drive was unplugged simply boot Windows from the hard drive's (`/dev/sda`) MBR.

---

I installed GRUB (2) to `/dev/sdb`, but when I tried to boot from the flash drive I got the following message:

> Grub Loading

After a couple of seconds I got an additional message:

> Read Error

For testing purposes, I tried to delete the contents of `/boot`, and I got the same message after booting again from the flash drive.

---

**PARTITIONING DETAILS**

`/dev/sda` (Hard Drive):

```
MBR: Windows Bootloader
/dev/sda1 - Windows System Partition
/dev/sda2 - Windows Boot Partition
/dev/sda3 - Windows Data Partition
/dev/sda4 - Linux partition
```

`/dev/sdb` (USB Flash Drive):

```
MBR: GRUB
/dev/sdb1 - Linux /boot Partition
```

---

**GRUB DETAILS**

`/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cryptdevice=/dev/disk/by-uuid/$SDA4_UUID:vg root=/dev/mapper/vg-root resume=/dev/mapper/vg-swap cryptkey=/dev/disk/by-uuid/$SDB1_UUID:ext2:/key"
..
GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true
```

**Installation command**

```
grub-install --target=i386-pc --recheck /dev/sdb
```

I'm using Arch Linux.

Comment: Did you include the USB hook in your `mkinitcpio.conf` before generating your intrd?

Comment: Yes I did. As well as all other necessary hooks (usb, encrypt, lvm2, ...).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
grub-install --target=i386-pc --recheck /dev/sdb1
```

Note the /dev/sdb1 which appears to be your USB device.

```
MBR: GRUB
/dev/sdb1 - Linux /boot Partition
```

Maybe try this :

```
title Start Ubuntu from USB DISK (PC)
root (cd)
kernel /boot/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper noprompt cdrom-detect/try-usb=true persistent
initrd /boot/initrd.lz
boot
```

Comment: Getting the following messages: `warning: File system 'ext2' doesn't support embedding [...] Embedding is not possible [...].`
`--force` does not help either  - `error: blocklists are invalid`.

Answer (score 0):

Two things: could you wipe the usb key first? I'm getting the impression a laconic "read error" message comes from older versions of grub.

Have you checked the contents of your `grub.cfg`?  `GRUB_DISABLE_UUID_LINUX` may not do what you want where there are multiple drives ([it will pass a device node name](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Specific_Entries)).  I would rerun `update-grub` with that line commented out.