# use bootable disk to redirect to flash drive

Tags: boot, usb, dual-boot

So, here's a crazy request.  For reasons unknown, I'm working with a BIOS which doesn't have to option to boot from USB devices, but I really want to boot off my flash drive.  The BIOS does allow me to boot from a CD (or, obviously, the hard drive, but that's not useful to me).

Is there some way I can create a CD/DVD that will allow me to then boot off my flash drive? I [read this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53681/linux-on-hard-drive-partition-bootloader-on-usb-flash-drive), which is a bit beyond my level, but I think it's similar to what I want to do. Can I put Grub (or some other bootloader) on a disk, and set it to allow me to boot from USB device?

Answer (score 0):

Download [`PLoP` Boot Manager](https://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/download.html) and burn it onto your CD.

Reboot and boot the CD or DVD. `PLoP` Boot Manager should start, then select your USB drive now and it should work.